# Check if Edittext is empty and if it is not then perform a particular piece of task

Tags: java, android

I am making an app and I'm stuck with one problem. I want to know what can I do to make this happen:

I want to check if the edit text is empty or not and if it is not, then perform a particular piece of the task and if it is empty then make a toast which says please enter the names.

Here is my code: `

```
final TextView percentage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentage_text);
Button calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate_button);

    calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Random noGen = new Random();
            int number = noGen.nextInt(101);

            EditText firestName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_name);
            String firstNameString = firestName.getEditableText().toString();

            EditText secName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sec_name);
            String secNameString = secName.getEditableText().toString();
            percentage.setText(Integer.toString(number));

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The love score between " + firstNameString  +" & " + secNameString + " is "  + number + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    });
```

`

I know I can easily do this with if else statement but I am not able to do it

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: you are able to do it. give yourself a try!

Comment: I did But I'm not able to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(firestName.getText()!=null && 
   !firestName.getText().equals("") && secName.getText()!=null && 
   !secName.getText().equals("")){

   // do your task

}else{ 
  // show msg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check String variable that whether is empty or not. You can refer below code. You can find more String operation on Internet.

```
Button calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate_button);
 EditText firestName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_name);
 EditText secName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sec_name);

    calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Random noGen = new Random();
            int number = noGen.nextInt(101);

            String firstNameString = firestName.getEditableText().toString();
            String secNameString = secName.getEditableText().toString();

            if(!firstNameString.isEmpty() && !secNameString.isEmpty()){
                //Perform your task
            }

            percentage.setText(Integer.toString(number));

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The love score between " + firstNameString  +" & " + secNameString + " is "  + number + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code;

```
 EditText firestName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_name);
 String firstNameString = firestName.getEditableText().toString();

 EditText secName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sec_name);
 String secNameString = secName.getEditableText().toString();

 if(firstNameString.matches("") && secNameString.matches("")){
            //Do your code here
 }
```

Comment: using `String.isEmpty()` is easier to read than `String.matches("")`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(firestName.getText().toString().equals("")){
  //do some stuff
```

}`else{
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}`

Comment: Formatting the answer better would help.